# C++ - dynamically use either reference or local variable

Tags: c++, reference

I would like to do something like this (I'm aware that this won't compile):

```
struct Container{
    vector<int> storage;
};

float foo(Container* aContainer){
    if(aContainer!=NULL)
        vector<int>& workingStorage=aContainer->storage;
    else
        vector<int> workingStorage; 


    workingStorage.reserve(1000000);
    ....use workingStorage to calculate something......

    return calculated_result;
}
```

So - if i pass a Container to the function, i want that the function uses the vector in the container to work with instead of a local variable. If no container is provided, it should use a local variable.

of course I could just in the end of the function copy the local variable to the storage of the Container, but that's not what I want to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create a local `std::vector<int>` named `local_storage` for the case where a container is not provided by the caller, then create a reference to whatever container you are actually going to use.

```
std::vector<int> local_storage;

std::vector<int>& working_storage = aContainer 
                                        ? aContainer->storage 
                                        : local_storage;
```

Comment: +1: I was going to suggest using a pointer, as this is one use case where references don't cut it (they are not variables). But I really like this solution :-)

Comment: @James: You rightly pointed out on my (now deleted) answer that you can't bind a reference to a temporary variable.  But doesn't the ternary expression in your code also evaluate to a temporary variable?

Comment: @Oli: No; that's why I create `local_storage` first; it always gets created regardless of whether it is used.

Comment: @James: I realise that, but how does the reference bind "through" the ternary operator?

Comment: just curious - could this also be achieved using if-else instead of ? operator?

Comment: @Oli: Oh, I see what you mean now. No; if I recall correctly, if both of the branches of the conditional operator are lvalue expressions, the conditional expression itself is an lvalue expression. I don't recall all the exact details off the top of my head, but it's something to that effect.

Comment: @Mat: No; since a reference must be bound to an object when it is initialized and you can't rebind a reference, you must use the conditional operator for this.  You could use a pointer if you wanted, but in my opinion this way using a reference is _much_ cleaner than using a pointer.

Comment: @James: Interesting.  So (in)formally, given `T a, b;`, the type of `(expr) ? a : b` is `T &`, and not `T`?

Comment: @Oli: Informally and to the best of my recollection, yes.  This also allows the conditional operator to be used on the left hand side, as in `(expr ? a : b) = T()`.

Comment: @James: Well, +1 for providing me with the thing I learnt today!

Comment: @Oli:  The "formal" phrasing is:  "If the second and third operands are lvalues and have the same type, the result is of that type and is an lvalue"  (C++03 5.16/4).

Answer (score 3):

One way to approach this problem is to break the function `foo` into 2 functions

```
float foo(Container* aContainer){ 
  if(aContainer!=NULL) {
    return foo_core(aContainer->storage);
  } else { 
    vector<int> workingStorage;  
    return foo_core(workingStorage);
}

float foo_core(vector<int>& workingStorage) { 
  ... 
  // rest of original foo
}
```

Comment: +1 no as nifty as James' but it makes up for it with its clarity.

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<int> temp;
vector<int>& workingStorage = (aContainer!=NULL) ? aContainer->storage : temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

The design is *apparently* horrible. But given that an optional externally provided storage is what you want, JaredPar (his answer) has a good idea. Cleaning that further up:

```
struct Container
{
    vector<int> storage;
};

double foo( vector<int>& workingStorage )
{
    workingStorage.reserve( 1000000 );
    //....use workingStorage to calculate something......
    return calculated_result;
}

double foo( Container& storageProvider )
{
    return foo( storageProvider.storage );
}

double foo()
{
    vector<int> storage;
    return foo( storage );
}
```

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make sure that `aContainer->storage` is initialized before you pass `aContainer` it to `foo`. That makes your code lot more neater. Have an `assert` statement at the start of the function to check `aContainer->storage` for NULL.

Comment: because I do not want to enforce having to provide a container.